# Web Apps don't show up in launcher or messaging menu

Tags: unity, webapps

I upgraded to 12.10 and I'm excited to use the web apps feature but it's not working!
I did everything by the book:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
```

I integrated my online accounts and installed Gmail web app on Chromium (version 22.0.1229.94). I got in my password and the magic didn't happen. There's an extension added to Chromium but no Gmail in messaging menu and no Gmail icon on launcher. The same thing for Facebook and YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug, look at this bur report:
[bug report at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1068662)

Comment: :// hope it gets fixed soon

Answer (score 0):

Which book did you read? You don't need a PPA for webapps in 12.10, it comes built in!

You can remove the PPA:

- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

And then it should be working. (You might need to logout and back in)

Comment: "the book": [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-install-ubuntus-new-web-apps-feature)

Web apps install promp didn't show up till I installed that PPA.

Comment: That book is out of date!

Answer (score 0):

Are you pinning it to the launcher?

Because my launcher is hidden I didn't notice until I pinned them there.

Comment: I used firefox to open the web apps and pined them to the launcher because now I lost the chromium extension hhh :$